# Google Script API + Oauth + Tumblr

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, tumblr

#### Hello,

I'm trying to acess, perform a post, into Tumblr with Oauth api provided by Tumblr) http://tumblr.com/api). I'm using ***Google Script*** and I've tryied too many solutions but anyone worked. To implement i've basaed myself into this(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/twitter_tutorial) Google script twitter tutorial, once on Tumblr API web page they say that twitter api is almost the same that tumblr.

### Contextualizing,

I've already set the Oauth class methods with data below and substituted consumer and secret keys with values got from the api i've created.

```
var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("tumblr");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl(
      "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl(
      "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl(
      "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(<i>consumerkey</i>);
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(<i>consumerSecret</i>);
```

### Error,

The code below isnt working as it should be.

```
var requestData = {

      "method": "POST",
      "oAuthServiceName": "tumbler",
      "oAuthUseToken": "always"
    };
     var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
       "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{blog}.tumblr.com/post?type=text&body=word",
          requestData);
```

The Script to Twitter is almost the same and it works. Im able to perform tweets.

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
          "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json?status=" + tweet,
          requestData);
```

#### Response From Server

Request failed for  returned code 400. Server response: {"meta":{"status":400,"msg":"Bad Request"},"response":{"errors":["Post cannot be empty."]}}

#### Possible Solutions

A possible solution can work using this information(got from tumblr.com/api):
OAuth
The API supports the OAuth 1.0a Protocol, **accepting parameters via the Authorization header, with the HMAC-SHA1 signature method only.** There's probably already an OAuth client library for your platform.

My question is, what am I doing wrong?(my post inst empty, i have 2 params). Had anyone had the same problem? Someone has suggestions?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the tumblr api, but your http post is empty (the oAuth parameters aren't in the post body, they're advanced options), the body of the post needs to go in the "payload" parameter. See the section "Advanced parameters" [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). Or, as you aren't using the post can't you use a get request instead? Remove the `method: POST` parameter (GET is the default).

Answer (score 1):

Thank You very much Daniel. It worked now!!

Everybody that want use Tumblr + Google Script API + oAuth can use de code below to perform posts.

I created I Google Spreadsheet and then a script there. Before to be able to post I neded to create and app into tumblr.com/api and get secret and consumer keys. Also I've deployed the Google script as an web app(ensure that the version is the last one(the final code)) before to create a new version. After that you go tu publish > deploy as web app !

That twitter tutorial I put on my first question is the only path you need to conclude your job.

```
function authorize() {
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("tumblr");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl(
      "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl(
      "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl(
      "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(getConsumerKey());
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(getConsumerSecret());

  var requestData = {
    "oAuthServiceName": "tumblr",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always"
  };
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{your_blog}.tumblr.com/posts/queue",
      requestData);
}


function doGet(e) {
  var tweet = e.parameter.tumblr;

 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Approved");
 var panel = app.createFlowPanel();

authorize();

 var encodedTweet = encodeURIComponent(tweet);

   var payload =
   {
     "body" : encodedTweet,
     "type" : "text"
   };

 var requestData = {
   "method" : "POST",
      "oAuthServiceName": "tumblr",
      "oAuthUseToken": "always",
      "payload" : payload
 };
    try {
      var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
          "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{your_blog}.tumblr.com/post",
          requestData);
          panel.add(app.createLabel().setText("You have approved: \"" + tweet + "\""));
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
      panel.add(app.createLabel().setText(e));
    }   
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}
```